# Incoming e-mail stop in "drop" folder

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, incoming-email, smtp

I have library configured to receive attachments. I configured the SMTP and SharePoint to receive e-mail, in my old scenery SharePoint 2010 this worked, but in migrated SharePoint 2013 don't work. The e-mail stop in "drop" folder.

Can anyone help me?